# Get UTF-8 in Uppercase using XDocument

Tags: c#, .net, xml, declaration, linq-to-xml

I need to have XML encoding and version at the top of my XML document which I am making with `XDocument`.

I have this but it is in lowercase, and it needs to be in uppercase.

What do I need to do?

I declare a new XML document using the `XDocument` class called 'doc'.

I save this to a file using `doc.Save();`.

I have tried:

- `doc.Declaration.Encoding.ToUpper();`
- Declaring a new `XDeclaration`
- Typing the Encoding in uppercase and setting my `doc.Declaration` to my `XDeclaration`.

It still comes through in lowercase.

Comment: Why do you need it in uppercase? It should make no difference to a standards conformant XML parser.

Comment: I agree, however it's not up to me, it needs to be in uppercase. I have tried "doc.Declaration.Version.ToUpper", declararing a new XDeclaration, typing the version in uppercase and setting my "doc.Declaration" to my XDeclaration. It still comes through in lowercase, I am using doc.Save(); thanks

Comment: Please edit your question and update it with the details you just put in your comment. These may be overlooked by people reading your question otherwise.

Comment: Did you try looping through all `doc.Declaration` attributes and `ToUpper`ing the attribute names?

Comment: Yes, I get Object reference not set to an instance of an object. When I try 'doc.Declaration.Version = "UTF-8";' I get the same error on this line of code.

Comment: `Version` is not the same as `encoding`.

Comment: Sorry, I said Version, I meant encoding, I get the same error with encoding.

Comment: @Oded I am really stuck here, if you could help me I would be forever grateful!

Comment: I would give an answer, by I don't know XDocument and LINQ to XML all that well. Sorry. Be patient, someone in the know will answer this.

Comment: I used StreamReader and StreamWriter to basically open the file and do a find and replace on "utf-8" to "UTF-8", bit of a hack but it works for now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create custom `XmlTextWriter`, e.g.:

```
public class CustomXmlTextWriter : XmlTextWriter
{
    public CustomXmlTextWriter(string filename)
        : base(filename, Encoding.UTF8)
    {

    }

    public override void WriteStartDocument()
    {
        WriteRaw("<?xml VERSION=\"1.0\" ENCODING=\"UTF-8\"?>");
    }

    public override void WriteEndDocument()
    {
    }
}
```

Then use it:

```
using (var writer = new CustomXmlTextWriter("file.xml"))
{
    doc.Save(writer);
}
```

Comment: It's very far from perfect. It's not even XML. XML allows (indeed prefers) the encoding name to be in upper case, but the keywords "encoding" and "version" must be lower case.

Comment: but this code looses the formatting, how do you preserve the formatting

Answer (score 1):

Working solution, using XmlDocument:

```
 myXmldoc.FirstChild.Value = "version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"";
```

As user726720 pointed out, the answer give by Kirill Polishchuk losses the formatting and requires mode code.